# Looping in python function and class

Tags: python

My input data is:
    ANG 
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0
    0.0

My desired output should be:

```
ANG 
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
100
0.3
```

I wrote my code using class and functions.
Here is my code.

```
class Calculate:
def angCal(self,dir,mag,string):
    cnt=0
     if cnt<=6:
        f4.write(string)
        cnt+=1
    elif cnt==7:
        string=str(dir)+"\n"
        f4.write(string)
        cnt+=1
   elif cnt==8:
        string=str(mag)+"\n"
        f4.write(string)
        cnt+=1
   if cnt==9:
        f4.write(string)
        cnt+=1
obj=Calculate()

f4=open("Out.txt",'w')
f1=open("Input.txt",'r')
for line in f1.readlines():
   string=line    
   if re.match(r'ANG',string):
      dir=100
      mag=0.3
      obj.angCal(dir,mag,string)
```

Codeis not working as desired.Please help

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: Now the output is not matching the required output

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: It's me or you are not looping at all?

Comment: Code is not working.PLease help to fix this to achievethe desiredoutput

Comment: There is multiple issue with your code/question: incorrect indentation, missing parenthesis after `obj=Calculate`, how do you create the `f4` variable, how do you read you input data, what is your output. The code that you provided is not a minimal working example. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated my code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should indent your code properly, instantiate your `Calculate` object, make the `angCal` accept `self` since it's an instance method, use a loop to iterate over the lines of the input string after splitting it, and fix your `if` conditions:

```
import re

class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    def angCal(self, dir, mag, string):
        cnt = 0
        for line in string.splitlines():
            if cnt == 8:
                self.file.write(dir)
            elif cnt == 9:
                self.file.write(mag)
            else:
                self.file.write(line)
            self.file.write('\n')
            cnt += 1

with open('input.txt') as f:
    string = f.read()
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f4:
    obj = Calculate(f4)
    if re.match(r'ANG', string):
        dir = 100
        mag = 0.3
        obj.angCal(dir, mag, string)
```

Comment: It is not working .The string ANG
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0''' is searched in a file which is stored in a file pointer f4. How to pass this string from a file and compute the function inside the class. Please help ..

Comment: Yes, and you can easily adapt the code above to read from a file and write to another file instead. I made the input a string and output with `print` so that people can easily try the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how you can read from a file and write to another file.

Comment: Oops I typed too fast. Fixed now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you can open the output file outside the class and use the file descriptor to initialize the class.

Comment: It is not working.i have tried.Now my output is same as input. It is not updating. Please help